# How to fine tune custom gpt 3.5 on conversations?

Tags: chatgpt, openai, chatgpt-3.5, structured-data, json

As far as i know, i only can train based on Q&A, like this: `{"prompt": "<prompt text>", "completion": "<ideal generated text>"}`

How can i train conversations? I only know of this Q&A way. I trained it with the example of the official docs (https://openai.com/blog/gpt-3-5-turbo-fine-tuning-and-api-updates).

Answer (score 0):

#### OpenAI overview: chat conversations belong to text generation fine-tuning

There is an overview on chat models at OpenAi [Endpoint -- Chat](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat) on the main OpenAI website which also links "Chat Completions" which turn out to be nothing but [Text generation models](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation), thus, your conversation model is nothing but a form of *text generation* fine-tuning.

If you follow that link, you will find that text generation has again the first chapter [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/chat-completions-api):

> Chat models take a list of messages as input and return a
> model-generated message as output. Although the chat format is
> designed to make multi-turn conversations easy, it’s just as useful
> for single-turn tasks without any conversation.
>
> An example Chat Completions API call looks like the following:
>
> ```
> from openai import OpenAI
> client = OpenAI()
>
> response = client.chat.completions.create(
>   model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
>   messages=[
>     {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
>     {"role": "user", "content": "Who won the world series in 2020?"},
>     {"role": "assistant", "content": "The Los Angeles Dodgers won the World Series in 2020."},
>     {"role": "user", "content": "Where was it played?"}
>   ]
> )
> ```
>
> The main input is the messages parameter. Messages must be an array of
> message objects, where each object has a role (either "system",
> "user", or "assistant") and content. Conversations can be as short as
> one message or many back and forth turns.
>
> Typically, a conversation is formatted with a system message first,
> followed by alternating user and assistant messages.
>
> The system message helps set the behavior of the assistant. For
> example, you can modify the personality of the assistant or provide
> specific instructions about how it should behave throughout the
> conversation. However note that the **system message is optional** and the
> model’s behavior without a system message is likely to be similar to
> using a generic message such as "You are a helpful assistant."
>
> **The user messages provide requests or comments for the assistant to
> respond to. Assistant messages store previous assistant responses, but
> can also be written by you to give examples of desired behavior.**
>
> Including conversation history is important when user instructions
> refer to prior messages. In the example above, the user’s final
> question of "Where was it played?" only makes sense in the context of
> the prior messages about the World Series of 2020. **Because the models
> have no memory of past requests, all relevant information must be
> supplied as part of the conversation history in each request.** If a
> conversation cannot fit within the model’s token limit, it will need
> to be shortened in some way.
> ...
> An example Chat Completions API response looks as follows:
>
> ```
> {   
>   "choices": [
>     {
>       "finish_reason": "stop",
>       "index": 0,
>       "message": {
>         "content": "The 2020 World Series was played in Texas at Globe Life Field in Arlington.",
>         "role": "assistant"
>       },
>       "logprobs": null
>     }   ],   "created": 1677664795,   "id": "chatcmpl-7QyqpwdfhqwajicIEznoc6Q47XAyW",   "model":
> "gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",   "object": "chat.completion",   "usage": {
>     "completion_tokens": 17,
>     "prompt_tokens": 57,
>     "total_tokens": 74
>   } 
> }
> ```

#### Step by step with another example

Thus, you only need to put more messages in the content list, and you will train the model on a conversation. If you only put one question and one answer, it also helpful.

In the following, I will show how you how to build a fine-tuning model on conversations. Mind that you might get a better outcome the more messages you feed.

##### Fine-tune a model on conversations

To fine-tune a model on conversations, you can follow the mere OpenAI fine-tuning guide. From OpenAI [Capabilities - Fine-tuning - Example format](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/example-format):

> In this example, our goal is to create a chatbot that occasionally
> gives sarcastic responses, these are three training examples
> (conversations) we could create for a dataset:
>
> ```
> {"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "Marv is a factual chatbot
> that is also sarcastic."}, {"role": "user", "content": "What's the
> capital of France?"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "Paris, as if
> everyone doesn't know that already."}]} {"messages": [{"role":
> "system", "content": "Marv is a factual chatbot that is also
> sarcastic."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Who wrote 'Romeo and
> Juliet'?"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "Oh, just some guy named
> William Shakespeare. Ever heard of him?"}]} {"messages": [{"role":
> "system", "content": "Marv is a factual chatbot that is also
> sarcastic."}, {"role": "user", "content": "How far is the Moon from
> Earth?"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "Around 384,400 kilometers.
> Give or take a few, like that really matters."}]}
> ```
>
> The conversational chat format is required to fine-tune gpt-3.5-turbo.

Thus, gpt-3.5-turbo can be fine-tuned. Begin like this, without quotes, see Stack Overflow [How to set env variable in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44251637/11154841):

```
%set_env OPENAI_API_KEY=sk-abcdef12345..................
```

And then:

```
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

file_object = client.files.create(
  file=open("mydata.jsonl", "rb"),
  purpose="fine-tune"
)
```

What is in the file_object?

```
> FileObject(id='file-abc123.....................', bytes=123456,
> created_at=170123456, filename='myfile.jsonl', object='file',
> purpose='fine-tune', status='processed', status_details=None)
```

I create the `FileObject` object `file_object` so that I can get its items, mainly its `id` with `file_object.id`, see [How to get the items inside of an OpenAIobject in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74524530/11154841). In the following, I need this `id` as the `training_file`.

This callable `Jobs.create()` needs to be filled with arguments, at least with `model` and `training_file`:

```
import inspect
inspect.signature(client.fine_tuning.jobs.create)
```

Out:

```
> <Signature (*, model: "Union[str, Literal['babbage-002',
> 'davinci-002', 'gpt-3.5-turbo']]", training_file: 'str',
> hyperparameters: 'job_create_params.Hyperparameters | NotGiven' =
> NOT_GIVEN, suffix: 'Optional[str] | NotGiven' = NOT_GIVEN,
> validation_file: 'Optional[str] | NotGiven' = NOT_GIVEN,
> extra_headers: 'Headers | None' = None, extra_query: 'Query | None' =
> None, extra_body: 'Body | None' = None, timeout: 'float |
> httpx.Timeout | None | NotGiven' = NOT_GIVEN) -> 'FineTuningJob'>
```

-> `training_file: 'str'`:

> ... training_file is the file ID that was returned when the training file was uploaded to the OpenAI API.

And:

-> `suffix: 'Optional[str]`:

> You can customize your fine-tuned model's name using the suffix parameter.

I also got some insight into the parameters at [How can I add options and hyperparameters to the fine-tuning command in new Fine-Tuning API?](https://community.openai.com/t/how-can-i-add-options-and-hyperparameters-to-the-fine-tuning-command-in-new-fine-tuning-api/333529/2) with the example:

```
openai.FineTune.create(
    model_engine=model_engine,
    n_epochs=n_epochs,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    learning_rate=learning_rate,
    max_tokens=max_tokens,
    training_file=os.path.abspath(training_file),
    validation_file=os.path.abspath(validation_file),
)
```

Therefore, the code is (and I add "n_epochs":2 to avoid the default of 10 epochs):

```
fine_tuning_job_object = client.fine_tuning.jobs.create(
  # training_file="mydata.jsonl", #WRONG 
  training_file=file_object.id, #RIGHT (must be the "id")
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo"
  hyperparameters={
    "n_epochs":2
  },
  suffix="v1"
)
```

You could fill also the number of epochs and other parameters, but OpenAI [Capacities - Fine-tuning - Iterating on hyperparameters](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/iterating-on-hyperparameters) says that you should start with the defaults:

> We allow you to specify the following hyperparameters:
>
> ```
> epochs
> learning rate multiplier
> batch size
> ```
>
> We recommend initially training without specifying any of these,
> allowing us to pick a default for you based on dataset size, then
> adjusting if you observe the following:
>
> If the model does not follow the training data as much as expected
> increase the number of epochs by 1 or 2.
> This is more common for tasks for which there is a single ideal
> completion (or a small set of ideal completions which are similar).
> Some examples include classification, entity extraction, or structured
> parsing. These are often tasks for which you can compute a final
> accuracy metric against a reference answer.
> If the model becomes less diverse than expected decrease the number of
> epochs by 1 or 2.
> This is more common for tasks for which there are a wide range of
> possible good completions.
> If the model does not appear to be converging, increase the learning
> rate multiplier.
>
> You can set the hyperparameters as is shown below:
>
> ```
> client.fine_tuning.jobs.create(  
>   training_file="file-abc123",
>   model="gpt-3.5-turbo",   
>   hyperparameters={
>     "n_epochs":2
>   } 
> )
> ```

Mind that the suffix must be short, I tried it with length 39 and got:

```
> BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': 'invalid
> suffix: _my_too_long_suffix................., ensure this value has
> at most 18 characters', 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param':
> 'suffix', 'code': None}}
```

It can have 18 characters at most.

Here is what you get as an object if you pass the few arguments above to `Jobs.create()`:

```
print(fine_tuning_job_object)
```

Out:

```
> FineTuningJob(id='ftjob-xyz987................',
> created_at=1701234567, error=None, fine_tuned_model=None,
> finished_at=None, hyperparameters=Hyperparameters(n_epochs=2,
> batch_size='auto', learning_rate_multiplier='auto'),
> model='gpt-3.5-turbo-0613', object='fine_tuning.job',
> organization_id='org-abcdef123456.............', result_files=[],
> status='validating_files', trained_tokens=None,
> training_file='file-abc123..................', validation_file=None)
```

You get a lot of defaults that you should tweak later to find a better output.

There is also:

> error=None, fine_tuned_model=None

Thus, the fine-tuning has perhaps not worked. I go on since I guess that this parameter does not mean this. I just check check whether the `Jobs.create()` has worked by searching for the model name. Therefore, I take the code from the OpenAI guide again, at the end of [Create a fine-tuned model](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/create-a-fine-tuned-model):

```
print(client.fine_tuning.jobs.list(limit=1))
```

That shows the latest model that was made.

Out:

```
> SyncCursorPage[FineTuningJob](data=[FineTuningJob(id='ftjob-xyz987................',
> created_at=1701234567, error=Error(code='invalid_n_examples',
> message='Training file has 1 example(s), but must have at least 10
> examples', param='training_file'), fine_tuned_model=None,
> finished_at=None, hyperparameters=Hyperparameters(n_epochs=2,
> batch_size='auto', learning_rate_multiplier='auto'),
> model='gpt-3.5-turbo-0613', object='fine_tuning.job',
> organization_id='org-abcdef123456.............', result_files=[],
> status='failed', trained_tokens=None,
> training_file='file-abc123..................', validation_file=None)],
> object='list', has_more=True)
```

And we see that there is an error:

```
> error=Error(code='invalid_n_examples', message='Training file has 1
> example(s), but must have at least 10 examples'
```

Thus, run it all again with at least 10 examples, I just copy them here as dummies. Mind: do not press any enter for a new line, it must be jsonl format, all in one line. By the way, jsonl does not care about spaces.

```
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "The chatbot wants to help."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Some question is written here."},    {"role": "assistant", "content": "Some helping answer."}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "The chatbot wants to help."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Some question is written here."},    {"role": "assistant", "content": "Some helping answer."}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "The chatbot wants to help."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Some question is written here."},    {"role": "assistant", "content": "Some helping answer."}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "The chatbot wants to help."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Some question is written here."},    {"role": "assistant", "content": "Some helping answer."}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "The chatbot wants to help."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Some question is written here."},    {"role": "assistant", "content": "Some helping answer."}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "The chatbot wants to help."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Some question is written here."},    {"role": "assistant", "content": "Some helping answer."}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "The chatbot wants to help."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Some question is written here."},    {"role": "assistant", "content": "Some helping answer."}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "The chatbot wants to help."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Some question is written here."},    {"role": "assistant", "content": "Some helping answer."}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "The chatbot wants to help."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Some question is written here."},    {"role": "assistant", "content": "Some helping answer."}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "The chatbot wants to help."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Some question is written here."},    {"role": "assistant", "content": "Some helping answer."}]}
```

Then run the code above again with this dummy jsonl file or your own file instead.

```
print(fine_tuning_job_object)
```

Out:

```
> FineTuningJob(id='ftjob-xyz987................',
> created_at=1701234567, error=None, fine_tuned_model=None,
> finished_at=None, hyperparameters=Hyperparameters(n_epochs=2,
> batch_size='auto', learning_rate_multiplier='auto'),
> model='gpt-3.5-turbo-0613', object='fine_tuning.job',
> organization_id='org-abcdef123456.............', result_files=[],
> status='validating_files', trained_tokens=None,
> training_file='file-abc123..................', validation_file=None)
```

Again, we see

> error=None, fine_tuned_model=None

```
print(client.fine_tuning.jobs.list(limit=1))
```

Out:

```
SyncCursorPage[FineTuningJob](data=[FineTuningJob(id='ftjob-123abc...............', created_at=1706123456, error=None, fine_tuned_model=None, finished_at=None, hyperparameters=Hyperparameters(n_epochs=2, batch_size=1, learning_rate_multiplier=2), model='gpt-3.5-turbo-0613', object='fine_tuning.job', organization_id='org-123abc................', result_files=[], status='validating_files', trained_tokens=None, training_file='file-123abc.................', validation_file=None)], object='list', has_more=True)
```

You can then check the latest model that you built with:

```
list(client.models.list())[-1]
```

Out:

```
Model(id='ft:gpt-3.5-turbo-0613:myorganizationname:v1:123abc.....', created=1706123456, object='model', owned_by='myorganizationname')
```

You need this to know the model id that will be the input parameter for asking questions to the fine-tuning model. I struggled with finding the right argument for the model parameter in the next code block for a long time, always getting:

```
> NotFoundError: Error code: 404 - {'error': {'message': 'The model `` does not exist', 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': 'model_not_found'}}
```

And I am not the only one, see OpenAI community [Error: That model does not exist (HTTP status code: 404), but it DOES exist!](https://community.openai.com/t/error-that-model-does-not-exist-http-status-code-404-but-it-does-exist/25866), where the main clue was to check the models in the [Playground](https://platform.openai.com/playground), while you can also do this with code above, which is also the only way if you cannot log in at the Playground of your organization (like me).

Here is the code from the OpenAI Fine-tuning guide again:

```
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

response = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="ft:gpt-3.5-turbo:my-org:custom_suffix:id",
  messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Hello!"}
  ]
)
print(response.choices[0].message)
```

And then, fill as model parameter the output that you get from

```
dict(list(client.models.list())[-1])['id']
```

Out:

```
'ft:gpt-3.5-turbo-0613:language-technology-group-uhh:v1:8nVs29RO'
```

And this will give you an output like:

```
ChatCompletionMessage(content='Hi there! How can I assist you today?', role='assistant', function_call=None, tool_calls=None)
```

That is an answer from the fine-tuned model.