# BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': 'Invalid file format. Line 1, key "messages": ...one message must be from the assistant ...}}

Tags: chatgpt, openai, fine-tuning, json

I follow OpenAI [Capabilities - Fine-tuning](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning).

This is myfile.jsonl:

```
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "You are a chatbot that wants to help tourists how to to spend their time."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Why should I go to the wood nearby?"}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "You are a chatbot that wants to help tourists how to to spend their time."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Why should I go to the wood nearby?"}]}
------and copy this 8 times more to have the 10 examples that you must have for fine-tuning a model------
```

Here is the code for Jupyter Notebook to load it for fine-tuning, taken from OpenAI [Capabilities - Fine-tuning - Example Format](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/example-format):

```
%set_env OPENAI_API_KEY=sk-abc123...............................
```

```
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

client.files.create(
  file=open("myfile.jsonl", "rb"),
  purpose="fine-tune"
)
```

This throws:

```
> BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': 'Invalid file
> format. Line 1, key "messages": At least one message must be from the
> assistant', 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code':
> None}}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

##### This answer is not yet done (ongoing work)

*(Do not follow this until this remark has gone.)*

I see from OpenAI [Use a fine-tuning model](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/use-a-fine-tuned-model) that I make some legacy hints here.

> You may now specify this model as a parameter to in the Chat Completions (for gpt-3.5-turbo) or legacy Completions API (for babbage-002 and davinci-002), and make requests to it using the Playground.

Thus, `gpt-3.5-turbo` is the model to choose, the rest is legacy (=old).

---

*From here on, this answer is outdated:*

##### Warning: I seem to be in the wrong model here (see next heading). The answer is still technically right and helpful for those who do not want to train Question Answering models

It seems that against what I thought, the fine-tuning forces you to have an assistant message as one of the messages. That is bad news for me since I thought that I could train the fine-tuning model without any answers. Yet, the example format of the guide shows it as well:

```
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "Marv is a factual chatbot that is also sarcastic."}, {"role": "user", "content": "What's the capital of France?"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "Paris, as if everyone doesn't know that already."}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "Marv is a factual chatbot that is also sarcastic."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Who wrote 'Romeo and Juliet'?"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "Oh, just some guy named William Shakespeare. Ever heard of him?"}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "Marv is a factual chatbot that is also sarcastic."}, {"role": "user", "content": "How far is the Moon from Earth?"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "Around 384,400 kilometers. Give or take a few, like that really matters."}]}
```

As the error tells it, I have to add an assistant message. Since I do not have any answer for my question at hand, I made this assistant message the question, while I made the user message the text that the question is about.

I do not know whether this is good practice, you might try other things.

This is myfile.jsonl:

```
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "The chatbot wants to help."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Some text is written here."},    {"role": "assistant", "content": "Some question to the text."}]}
```

Good practice or not, how you fill it is up to you, I am just a beginner who tries to load that file at all. And this jsonl will be loaded:

```
> FileObject(id='file-abcdef123456', bytes=123456,
> created_at=1706123456, filename='myfile.jsonl', object='file',
> purpose='fine-tune', status='processed', status_details=None)
```

##### Mind that for a Question Answering model, this seems to be the wrong jsonl input

This is only a side remark again since the technical problem is solved by the answer, but the code that I showed is likely wrong or not good practice for question answering fine-tuning. Taken from the OpenAI Fine-tuning guide again:

> The conversational chat format is required to fine-tune gpt-3.5-turbo. For babbage-002 and davinci-002, you can follow the prompt completion pair format as shown below.

Thus, take the models `babbage-002` or `davinci-002`.

See GenAI SE [How to fine tune custom gpt 3.5 on conversations?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/654/3022).

If you check the OpenAI Fine-tuning guide twice, you understand this:

```
{"prompt": "<prompt text>", "completion": "<ideal generated text>"}
{"prompt": "<prompt text>", "completion": "<ideal generated text>"}
{"prompt": "<prompt text>", "completion": "<ideal generated text>"}
```

If you then leave out the "completion" message and put the text and the question in one user prompt (or split it into two user prompts, untested), you will have a question answering model with open questions, that is, without the answers during training, and the model will try answering the questions during fine-tuning (untested, but that is what GPT 3.5 was guessing without knowing 2024: just drop the completion message).

Comment: I did not have the time to check this further, but I will get to this hopefully in a week or two. My guess is that the Question Answering models of GPT are indeed legacy models since any chat can replace a question answering model. You see this right away if you chat with ChatGPT and ask it for an error in the code. It can answer to the context question. Thus, the chat is itself already a question answering model. I will check this further, but it is likely. A forced message from the assistant is likely to show the model how the chat bot shall reply (long or short, deepness, near context ...).